# Post upgradation, update and other commands are not working in ubuntu 22.04. GUI Broken

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager

Hope! everyone is doing well.
Post upgradation of ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 . I am getting the error "failed to fetch "http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/main/source/Sources 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]" while trying to update the ubuntu 22.04. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?
There are some more problems as well.

1. ubuntu-security-status - command not found
2. update-manager-d - command not found
3. add-apt-repository - command not found
4. do-release-upgrade - command not found
5. locate - can't locate any packages.
6. GUI is not working
7. LAN is not working only wifi working.

I am working on CLI.

Thanks & Regards,
Himanshu Yadav

Comment: You mention both 20.04 (*focal*) and 22.04 (*jammy*), but the error message you mention relates to Ubuntu 21.04 (*hirsute*). You won't be running Ubuntu 20.04 (*focal*) if you have that error message, so please check your facts.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: So many problems suggests that your release-upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 encountered serious problems. Since you did not mention seeing the error message, it might be simpler for you to back up your data and then reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: You have obsolete repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: @karel Thanks, everyone for sharing the input. Fortunately, I have resolved my issue. Here is the solution, which I hope will help others: 1. "us.archive.ubuntu" error: Thanks Karel, Yes I resolved the post-restore of my backup and I am able to update it.  2. add-apt-repository: sudo apt-get install software-properties-common 3. For the internet: I installed netplan.io 4. For GUI: sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop 5. To locate the issue: sudo apt-add repository.  Still, if you face a problem, please share it with me.